# 'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session' is null

Tags: asp.net, session-state

I have an ASP.NET website that has been deployed since 2008 with plenty of users. From time to time, I've made updates to the site and uploaded those changes to the server without problems.

However, today, I'm trying to run the site on my development environment and I keep getting errors any time the code tries to access session state. It appears `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session` is always `null`!

Any suggestions on where to look? It's been a while since I worked on it and am not 100% sure if I've worked on it with the current version of ASP.NET (4.0).

Other than that, the code's been working fine and I haven't made any changes since it was last working.

**More Information**

I've spent all morning on this but I apparently have a larger issue.

If I step through the code, I see that my page Load handler executes. At this point, Session is not null. After that, my specialized master page executes. After that, my general master page executes. I then step through load events for a couple of controls. This all seems very normal.

Then, if I keep executing, suddenly I'm loading a specialized master page for another page and Session is now null!

If I hit F5, it the original page shows. But somehow it is causing the other page to load and without session state. If I turn off debug mode, it appears to run normally.

Obviously, I have something strange happening. I need to determine why the other page is being loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My apologies. The information I provided was completely misguided and was not sufficient to resolve the issue.

The problem was actually due to some custom error handling that redirected to an error page. This was configured in web.config. This error page was using the master page that my code was mysteriously executing.

Apparently, an error was occurring within the GridView control. This is ASP.NET code and not my own, so I was unable to step through it or catch it with a regular handler.

This was hard to understand. If I was executing the Load event handler of my error page, then it would've been obvious. But it appears to have skipped over that. Thus, my confusion.

Answer (score 3):

Try to put a static page, something like `Test.aspx` and browse to that page. If it gets loaded, try to use `Session` property of the page in code behind. Do you still get the error? In that case, **Session** doesn't load. I suggest creating an HTTP Module and hooking into a method which is responsible for loading Session info. See what's wrong.

Comment: Hmm... Test.aspx loads just fine. And it looks like Session != null during Page_Load() in the code behind. This is very strange.

Comment: from `Session != null` I perceive that you meant session is not null, or it's working. In that case, you should show us part of your code. Somewhere that you use `Session` object.

Comment: Yes, in this case, Session is not null. (I'm using C# in my code behind.)

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess - did you deactivate sessionState for any reason? Anything like this:

```
 <sessionState mode="Off"/>
```

Comment: No, and I searched the entire solution for "sessionState". The matches I found were just where it was being read, and no results in any web.config.

Comment: Did you also check sessionState in any kind of parent web.config or even machine.config ?

Comment: Could you provide us with a complete piece of code. Eventually you could show us the whole file (with extension). I was wondering why you mentioned "System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session".. You wrote you check in a masterPage... Although this might not happen - why do you check for 'System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session' instead of "Session"? any special reason for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try checking the `global.asax` file or any other `pre-load events` and make sure the `Session` is not set to NULL explicitly.

Comment: The answer may not be correct, but may give a ray of light to debug the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your erring master page is calling code from some external class where the session object is not available?